# why I cannot reshape or resize my numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, resize, reshape

I have the following output for a

```
 [  1.   3.   5.   7.   9.  11.  13.  15.  17.  19.  21.  23.  25.  27.
    29.  31.  33.  35.  37.  39.  41.  43.  45.  47.  97.  99. 101. 103.
    105. 107. 109. 111. 113. 115. 117. 119. 121. 123. 125. 127. 129. 131.
    133. 135. 137. 139. 141. 143.]
```

I want to reshape it to the below

```
[[1.   3.   5.   7.   9.   11.  13.  15.]
 [17.  19.  21.  23.  25.  27.  29.  31.]
 [33.  35.  37.  39.  41.  43.  45.  47.]
 [97.  99. 101. 103.  105. 107. 109. 111.]
 [113. 115. 117. 119. 121. 123. 125. 127.]
 [129. 131. 133. 135. 137. 139. 141. 143.]]
```

I tried to use `a.resize(6, 8)`, but it gives me this error: "resize only works on single-segment arrays"
Also, when I am trying to use `a.reshape(6, 8)`, it gives me the same array.
I don't understand what is the reason for that as I have tested another array and worked well.

Comment: `reshape` does not work in-place.  It returns a new array: `b = a.reshape(6,8)`.  The `resize` method does work in-place, but as a result is picky about the kind of array that it works with.  Unless we need to change the total number of elements, we usually use `reshape`.

Answer (score 2):

try `a.reshape((8, 6))`
notice the double parentheses

```
a = np.array([1., 3., 5., 7., 9., 11., 13., 15., 17., 19., 21., 23., 25., 27.,
              29., 31., 33., 35., 37., 39., 41., 43., 45., 47., 97., 99., 101., 103.,
              105., 107., 109., 111., 113., 115., 117., 119., 121., 123., 125., 127., 129., 131.,
              133., 135., 137., 139., 141., 143.])
print(a.reshape((8, 6)))
```

out:

```
[[  1.   3.   5.   7.   9.  11.]
 [ 13.  15.  17.  19.  21.  23.]
 [ 25.  27.  29.  31.  33.  35.]
 [ 37.  39.  41.  43.  45.  47.]
 [ 97.  99. 101. 103. 105. 107.]
 [109. 111. 113. 115. 117. 119.]
 [121. 123. 125. 127. 129. 131.]
 [133. 135. 137. 139. 141. 143.]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

do notice that for the output you requested, the dimensions should be

```
a.reshape((6,8))
```

out:

```
[[  1.   3.   5.   7.   9.  11.  13.  15.]
 [ 17.  19.  21.  23.  25.  27.  29.  31.]
 [ 33.  35.  37.  39.  41.  43.  45.  47.]
 [ 97.  99. 101. 103. 105. 107. 109. 111.]
 [113. 115. 117. 119. 121. 123. 125. 127.]
 [129. 131. 133. 135. 137. 139. 141. 143.]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

you can read about NumPy's reshape here: [reshape documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Comment: oh sorry, I made a mistake. the initial array that I have put here is my output. I editted that.

Comment: the initial array is numpy.ndarray.

Comment: `x.reshape((4,5))` and `x.reshape(4,5)` are both ok.  For `np.zeros` the tuple shape is required, but `reshape` method allows either.

Comment: I still couldnt understand. I have variable a which is a <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.
I try reshape on other numpy.ndarray variables, and it workd but here it gives me the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
b = a.reshape((8,6))
```

and keep in mind 2 things, for future use of similar methods:

1. the reshape method takes a tuple as input, in that case `(8,6)` , calling `b = a.reshape(8,6)`  gives 2 int arguments to the method instead of the tuple it expects. always pay attention to the expected values. you can investigate that by just hovering over a function in pycharm and most editors.
2. in numpy, many methods do not manipulate the given object but rather return a new value for you to use.
   it is healthy to always check for that in documentation, in order to avoid catastrophic heartbreaks, trust me.